# Regular expression on Dates in Oracle

Tags: regex, oracle

I have date formats in all the possible permutations. MM/DD/YYYY, M/D/YYYY, MM/D/YYYY, M/DD/YYYY

Now I need to write a regular expression in Oracle DB to fetch different date formats from 1 column as is

Comment: Is there any other data except date in that column? Post sample data and desired output, please.

Comment: Don't try to work around erroneous input data. If possible, fix the input process (by educating your users, using DATE instead of VARCHAR2 as your column type).

Comment: no i just have dates in the above formats. sample data is 1/01/2006,
01/01/2017,
01/05/2012

Comment: And the datatype of that columns is?

Comment: the data type is varchar2

Comment: Another reason **not** to use `VARCHAR` datatype for **dates**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one:

```
with t(date_col) as (
select '01/01/2014' from dual
union all
select '1/2/2014' from dual
union all
select '01/3/2014' from dual
union all
select '1/04/2014' from dual
union all
select '11/1/14' from dual)
select date_col,
       case
         when regexp_instr(date_col, '^\d/\d/\d{4}$') = 1 then
          'd/m/yyyy'
         when regexp_instr(date_col, '^\d{2}/\d/\d{4}$') = 1 then
          'dd/m/yyyy'
         when regexp_instr(date_col, '^\d/\d{2}/\d{4}$') = 1 then
          'd/mm/yyyy'
         when regexp_instr(date_col, '^\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}$') = 1 then
          'dd/mm/yyyy'
         else
          'Unknown format'
       end date_format
  from t;

DATE_COL   DATE_FORMAT
---------- --------------
01/01/2014 dd/mm/yyyy
1/2/2014   d/m/yyyy
01/3/2014  dd/m/yyyy
1/04/2014  d/mm/yyyy
11/1/14    Unknown format
```

Comment: @akram Glad that it helped. Mark the question as answered, please.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what your goal is, but since months are always first, followed by day, you can use the following expression to get a date regardless of the input format:

```
 select to_date( column, 'mm/dd/yyyy') from ...
```

Comment: The goal is to find different date formats in the column, I have thousands of records for each format.

Comment: I think the point is that MM/DD/YYYY, M/D/YYYY, MM/D/YYYY, M/DD/YYYY are not considered different formats.

Comment: The validation is to check all the dates which are not coming this way MM/DD/YYYY, Its a bug when the date is passed with M/DD/YYYY . For ex : 01/01/2011 and the wrong one is 1/01/2011.

Answer (score 0):

You can select all records for which the following is true:

```
where [column_value] != to_char(to_date([column_value],'MM/DD/YYYY'),'MM/DD/YYYY')
```